# Set SimpleCV Camera resolution with the result of a function

Tags: python, camera, simplecv

I need to set the resolution of a photo taken with SimpleCV using the result returned by a function, this would be the code:

```
def resolutionselection():
    print"""
Ahora tenemos que escoger el formato y resolución de las fotos:
    1 - 10x15.
    2 - 15x20.
    """

    answer = raw_input("→")

    if answer == "1":
        print("Has seleccionado hacer las fotos en 10x15.\n")
        resolution = ['2304', '1536']
        return resolution
    elif answer == "2":
        print("Has seleccionado hacer las fotos en 15x20.\n")
        resolution = ['2048', '1536']
        return  resolution
    else:
        print("No estamos colaborando...")
        exit(0)

px = resolutionselection()
cam = Camera(prop_set={'width':px[0], 'height':px[1]})
```

But it gives me error:

```
TypeError: Expected CvCapture for argument 'capture'
```

EDIT:
I'm posting the full code, to clarify:
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import time
from SimpleCV import Camera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from sys import exit

sequence = 001          # Starts the sequence number for the photos.
event_name = "Event"    # Indicates the name of the event, used in the filename of the photos.
kiosk = "./"            # Without choosing, same folder as the program.
cam = Camera(prop_set={'width':2304, 'height':1536})    # Initializes the camera with HR 3:2 format.

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def kioskselection():
    print"""
Primero, tenemos que escoger el Kiosco que va a imprimir:
    1 - Kodak Wedding.
    2 - Kodak Voyage.
    """

    answer = raw_input("→\t")

    if answer == "1":
        print("Has seleccionado Kodak Wedding.\n")
        kiosk = "/media/kodakwedding/"
        return kiosk
    elif answer == "2":
        print("Has seleccionado Kodak Voyage. \n")
        kiosk = "/media/kodakvoyage/"
        return kiosk
    else:
        print("No estamos colaborando...")
        exit(0)

def resolutionselection():
    print"""
Ahora tenemos que escoger el formato y resolución de las fotos:
    1 - 10x15.
    2 - 15x20.
    """

    answer = raw_input("→\t")

    if answer == "1":
        print("Has seleccionado hacer las fotos en 10x15.\n")
        resolution = [2304, 1536]
        print(resolution)
        return resolution
    elif answer == "2":
        print("Has seleccionado hacer las fotos en 15x20.\n")
        resolution = [2048, 1536]
        return  resolution
        print(resolution)
    else:
        print("No estamos colaborando...")
        exit(0)

kiosk = kioskselection()
px = resolutionselection()
cam = Camera(prop_set={'width':px[0], 'height':px[1]})


print("PUSH DA BUTTON!")

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(17)
    if input_state == False:
        img = cam.getImage()
        img.save("%s%s - %d.jpg" % (kiosk, event_name, sequence))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Foto '%s - %d.jpg', guardada." % (event_name, sequence))
        sequence += 1
```